# Spring-tx: Rollback only if exception is uncaught by outmost method

Tags: spring, transactions, rollback

By default, spring framework can rollback when unchecked exception is thrown across the boundary of a transactional method. But in case of transaction propagation, I want to rollback the transaction only if the exception is uncaught by the outmost method (where the tx is started). Is it possible to configure spring this way?

```
@Transactional
public class OutterA {
    @Autowired
    private Inner inner;

    public void operationA1() {
        this.doSomething();
        inner.doSomething();
    }

    public void operationA2() {
        this.doSomething();
        try {
            inner.doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            inner.tryAnother();
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() {

    }
}

@Transactional
public class Inner {
    public void doSomething() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public void tryAnother() {

    }
}
```

In above code, I expect operationA1 to be rolled-back because the exception is not caught and causes the end of transaction, while operationA2 succeed because the exception is caught and correctly handled before transaction ends. But spring will rollback both.

```
// Non-transactional
public class OutterB {
    @Autowired
    private Inner inner;

    public void operationB() {
        try {
            inner.doSomething();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I expect operationB to be always rolled-back because the transaction is started by `Inner` and the exception is thrown across the transaction boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can play with `@Transactionl` annotation options like:

- `rollbackFor, rollbackForClassName`
- `noRollbackFor, noRollbackForClassName`

In your code snippet case if you put `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)` on your `InnerClass` your transaction will be not rollbacked. However putting `@Transactional` annotation on a class level will affect each public method in this class, so I recommend you to put this annotation separate on each method and define specific behavior using these options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, methods of `Inner` may also be called without a transaction thus it starts a new one. In which case, the transaction should rollback because the exception is not handled when the transaction ends.

Comment: Take a look at [propagation levels](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) you can define the different level for each method, and achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi, I think I need REQUIRED, which is the default. But the `Inner` class doesn't know whether the transaction is existing or a new one. Only the framework (interceptor) has that information.

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO. You can't change the behaviour of the code depending of whether you are called with an existing transaction or not. There is `REQUIRES_NEW` for that.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll Hi, IMO the behaviour is already different. If the transaction is a new one, it's committed when the method returns, and if the transaction is existing, it's not committed. So in case of exception, If the transaction is a new one, it should rollback when the method throws, and if the transaction is existing, it should not. Is that reasonable?

Comment: No it is not. I've already said so in two different channels.